# Processing an Image using Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've a 15 images which are stored locally. How do I transform these images to a array using tensorflow for a CNN type of Classification?

Comment: two ways : You can use the PIL library for example to convert your images  to an array and then use them easily. Or you can use the dataset API of tensorlfow to preprocess your images and pass them throw a generator (this method is recommended)

Answer (score 0):

Convert the image to numpy array format

```
import cv2
im = cv2.imread("some_image.tiff")
```

Reshape them to an arbitrary, but identical, size

```
def reshape(image_array):
    return np.reshape(image_array, [128, 128, 3])
```

Put them all in a list and then standardize them so they all have standardized pixel values using:

```
def per_image_standardization(arrays):
    sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
    standardized_tensors = tf.map_fn(lambda array:                            
        tf.image.per_image_standardization(array), 
                                           arrays)
    standardized_images = standardized_tensors.eval()
    return standardized_images
```